# Can Selenium be efficiently used to test many different user log ons?

Tags: testing, selenium, web-applications, selenium-webdriver, automation

By many I mean hundreds/thousands. I need to test features that many users will need to see/hear. Obviously these users have different permission levels and some are in different programs. Can a test case be written to pull userids and passwords from the db to test in this way efficiently? Or is this something that is best manually tested by spot checking different log ons?

Comment: Obviously you can. Can I know what you actually expect for?

Comment: You may want to use the @dataprovider annotation of TestNg to store the username and password in a 2D array and then dataprovider annotation will execute the login test for each value stored in the 2D array

Comment: Query db in before step of test and build a map of usernames, passwords, and whatever else, then iterate over the map in your test.

Answer (score 0):

Call the DB before you run the test to get your users/passwords/whatever else.

Are you using NUnit?  If so, you could use the Nunit [ValueSourceAttribute](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=valueSource&r=2.5) to get the data into your test and use a variable for the credentials during your login step.